# How to compare the current time with the existing date fields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

This is my Schema

```
{
    "from": {type: Date, required: true},
    "to": {type: Date, required: true},
    "slotname": {type: String, required: true},
    "createdAt": {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    "modifiedAt": {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    "isDeleted": {type: Boolean, default: false}
}
```

Using this schema I have created total 10 records. For these 10 records slotnames are `"slot1","slot2"..."slot10"`.

The `from` and `to` timings are `9-11, 11-1, 2-4, 4-6, 6-9, 9-11, 11-1, 2-4, 4-6, 6-9` respectively.

Now I need to compare these with `current time`.

Suppose if the current time is `11` it should return the documents consisting of `from` and `to` timings as `2-4, 4-6, 6-9 and 9-11`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @SambitD Actually I need to show the slots to customers based on time. The **from** and **to ** are the two fields consisting of full date format.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating any slot you should not keep date as from and to. Those are not for a particular day, right!

You can enter the hours value of the slot as integer. Let's take the first slot. There you can insert from as 2 and to as 4.

Then the query will be like

```
var tStamp = new Date();
var hr = tStamp.getHour();
query = {
        from: {
            $lte: hr
        }, 
        to: {
            $lte: hr
        }
    };
yourCollection.find(query).toArray(callbackFn);
```

See [$lte-mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/).

Comment: You should not store slot as string, as `$lte` won't work with string values, so keep the hours as integer only.